# How to fetch last 10 messages from IMAP server?

Tags: python, imap, imaplib

I use imaplib2 library to search the last 10 messages with such command:

```
imap_client.search(None, '{}:{}'.format(last_uid, last_uid - 9))
```

But to get `last_uid` I need exec every time command like this:

```
imap_client.select("INBOX", readonly=True)
```

to get last UID.

Are the any ways to:

1. get last UID without `select()` command fetch last 10 messages
2. without last UID. Maybe there are any search criterias like 'LAST' or '-10:'?

I can not exec command like this `client.search(None, 'ALL')`, because IMAP server have more than 50K messages.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting n most recent emails using IMAP and Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5632713/getting-n-most-recent-emails-using-imap-and-python)

Comment: @Joe, It's not duplicate. I can not exec 'ALL' criteria. Thanks for this moment, now edited question.

Comment: @Joe: if there were only one meaning of "last" it would be a duplicate. *sigh*

Comment: `UID`s are not guaranteed to be sequential, use sequence numbers instead. You can get the last sequence number with the `COUNT` returned when you select the mailbox.

Answer (score 4):

You can get the last UID using the `STATUS (UIDNEXT)` command. However, you have to select the mailbox in order to retrieve messages, and when you issue SELECT, you'll get a message count back, which the Python imaplib's `select` returns.

So all you need is:

```
(status, response_text) = mailbox.select("inbox")
# response_text usually contains only one bytes element that denotes
# the message count in an ASCII string
message_count = int(response_text[0].decode("ascii"))
```

and then you can fetch the messages by index from `message_count - 9` through `message_count`.

Note that messages are index starting at one.

Comment: `UIDNEXT` does *not* give you the last UID. From RFC 3501 "The next unique identifier value is intended to provide a means for a client to determine whether any messages have been delivered to the mailbox since the previous time it checked this value.  It is not intended to provide any guarantee that any message will have this unique identifier." There is no guarantee that UIDNEXT has any particular relationship with the last UID, other than it being greater than it.

Comment: That's right, there is no guarantee of that. But if you want the last few messages, retrieving [UIDNEXT-x,UIDNEXT> is the best single command IMO. If you're willing to engage in MSN arithmetic and use two commands you can do better (e.g. with UID SEARCH x-10:* where x is the value sent in EXISTS, then check your cache for those UIDs, then UID FETCH the resulting UIDs). MSN arithmetic is tricky though, and I wouldn't recommend MSN arithmetic to anyone. If anyone wants to try: that's a UID SEARCH command with MSN arguments.

Comment: BTW, that UIDs are close to consecutive on the server in question is an implication of the first paragraph of section 2.3.1.1. If they were *not* close to consecutive, then the assignment scheme would run into the 32-bit boundary before building up the 50k messages in that mailbox, see?

Comment: A more realistic example I'm thinking about: if you have a bunch of consecutive messages dumped into a mailbox, say 1-50, but then you delete 25-50, you'd only have UIDs 1-24, but UIDNEXT would be 51. Therefore, it's wrong to say that the highest number message is 50 - it's actually 24 in this case. If the assumption is that messages are never deleted from a mailbox (which I didn't see provided) and that UIDs are assigned consecutively (which I agree is reasonable) then I think it would hold. I'm thinking a better option might be using the `MAX` search option (RFC 4731)

Comment: That's also true and is a reason why using the ten UIDs just before UIDNEXT is a poor approach for small mailboxes. But in this case we know there are/were 50k messages there, which isn't something that happens when you delete a lot of messages. _Pogramming maxim number 42: You can always make the code more complicated by inventing some extra use cases or edge cases, and requiring it to support them._ This is what YAGNI is about.

Comment: I didn't get the sense from the question that no messages are ever deleted from the mailbox. As long as that's a possibility, I don't see why it matters how large the mailbox is. I have mailboxes with 100,000 messages in them, and I've also deleted tens of thousands of messages from it over time, but I can't see how I'd ever have a reliable way to get the max UID from the mailbox using UIDNEXT. This assumes that the n most recent messages delivered to the mailbox were not expunged, and I don't think that's a reasonable assumption, or that this is an edge case in general (think of an INBOX)

Answer (score 4):

For any future travelers who seek an answer to this, I came up with code from the hint given by @arnt.

```
svr = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(server)
if svr.login(user=user, password=password):
    print('User ' + user + ' logged in successfully.')
else:
    print('Login for the user ' + user + " was denied. Please check your credentials.")

x = svr.select('inbox', readonly=True)
num = x[1][0].decode('utf-8')
#from here you can start a loop of how many mails you want, if 10, then num-9 to num
resp, lst = svr.fetch(num, '(RFC822)')
body = lst[0][1]
email_message = email.message_from_bytes(body)
```

For me this was quite handy as I was accessing an email with more than 67000 emails in it.